# How can I get term from this kind of format line?

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm

The file looks like this:

```
本/O  实用新型/O  是/O  一种/O  用于/O  直接/O  驱动/O  电动汽车/O  None/O  的/O  电动汽车/B  电磁/M  自动/M  差速/M  驱动/M  电机/M  装置/E  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  
是/O  由/O  装/O  在/O  外壳/B  内/O  转轴/B  上/O  的/O  内/O  、/O  外/B  转子/E  构成/O  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  
内/O  、/O  外/B  转子/E  由/O  磁性/B  体/E  和/O  其上/O  的/O  线圈/B  绕组/E  构成/O  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  
外/B  转子/M  磁性/M  体/E  由/O  轴/O  经/O  隔离/O  轴承/B  装/O  在/O  内/B  转子/M  输出/M  轴/E  上/O  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X  None/X
```

each word endswith a tag('B' 'M' 'E' 'O' 'X'), 'B' stands for begin, 'M' means middle, 'E' means     end of the word, 'O' and 'X' is other tag, I want to get the whole word.

for example, "轴承/B  装/O  在/O  内/B  转子/M  输出/M  轴/E  上/O  None/X  "

In this line, it contains 2 terms, they are "`轴承`" and "`内转子输出轴`", how can I achieve this goal with python, thanks for your answer

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Show us the code you have written and we will help you with it.

Comment: this is the code that i wrote so far `def get_term():
 term_arr = open('term_arr.txt', 'w')
 with open('perdict_terms.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  term = []
  for line in lines:
   arr = []
   words = line.strip().split('  ')
   for word in words:
    if word.endswith('O'):
     continue
    elif word.endswith('X'):
     continue
    else:
     arr.append(word)
   print(arr)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
 get_term()
`, and **arr** looks like this `['电池/B', '模块/E', '性能/B']
['性能/B', '电池/B', '模块/M', '组/E', '电池/B']
['电池/B', '性能/B']
['性能/B', '模块/B', '性能/B']
[]`